How to reclaim water used for PCB cleaning?
We are repurposing a dishwasher to use for PCB cleaning. We are adding reverse osmosis & deionization filters to supply it deionized water. We plan on using Electrolube SWAT as our PCB cleaning detergent. I would like to reclaim the used water containing detergent and flux. Will these filters be enough? Link
This is a 4 stage RO unit, which will produce 0 TDS water.
Stage 1: 5 Micron Sediment Filter cartridge. (Removes sediments from the water).
Stage 2: Carbon Block Filter cartridge. (Removes Trihalomethanes, Pesticides, Volatile Organic Chemicals and 99.95% of Giardia and Cryptosporidium Cysts).
Stage 3: High quality Vontron membrane element. (Removed contaminants present in water including up to 99% of dissolved salts, Lead, Copper, Barium, Bacterial By-Products, Oestrogen and Silica.
Stage 4: High quality DI Resin. (Removes any further dissolved solids in the water, and 'polishes' the water, ensuring the TDS is 0)
I was also wondering if DI water on its own is enough to do the job.

While PCB(A) manufacturing is on-topic here, this mostly sounds like a chemistry question. Perhaps it is better ask at the chemistry site? Though they'll probably want the in-depth details of what substances all of this contains, particularly the detergent and the flux. Biological aspects of the cleaning are probably not very important since nobody is planning on drinking it.

"You will tend to get around 1 part pure water to 4 parts waste water". Seems barely worth it.

Uhm, you can buy water reclaimers for this purpose off the shelf. Why make your own? It's a highly specialized field and depends on the impurities you want to clean.
https://www.pickplacepodcast.com/episodes/ep33board-cleaning-w-mike-konrad-part-1

Comment only: "enough" for what purpose? || I am non-expert in this area BUT the specification of the RO filter makes me think that I'd be happy enough to drink its output - after remineralisation because the water is so pure. || For interest, why do you want to do this? Given the expense I assume that the aim has significant benefit. ||The RO unit outputs 80% of its input as waste. This is only about 25% more contaminated than the original. Simpler lower cost filtering may also reclaim this for many purposes. A 'sand filter' or 'slow sand filter' come to mind. SF uses flocculants. SSF don't

SSF: https://wiki2.org/en/Slow_sand_filter  and SF: https://wiki2.org/en/Sand_filter
